# Increment in the value of each row based on iterations in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I have an increment on a column in each row based on the values of other column till specific iterations?

For example:
There are 2 columns `Iterations` and `IncrementRatio`. The value of `Iterations` is `5` and `IncrementRatio` is `5000`. The query is supposed to generate `10` records only. Once the iteration number is reached the remaining rows should keep the last value. So based on this scenario I should be able to get something like this.

```
 MyCount
 ---------
 5000
 10000
 15000
 20000
 25000
 25000
 25000
 25000
 25000
 25000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed you always wanted fixed `10` rows result. This is achieve with `CROSS JOIN` to a derived table with 10 rows. In the solution, i am using [Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to generate 10 rows. You can replace it with a `tally` table if you have one.

```
-- create the sample table for demonstration of the query
declare @table table
(
    Id              int identity,
    Iterations      int,
    IncrementRatio  int
)

-- insert original sample data plus one extra
insert into @table values (5, 5000), (3, 1000)

-- the query
select  *,
        MyCount = case  when  n < Iterations 
                        then  n * IncrementRatio
                        else  Iterations * IncrementRatio
                        end
from    @table 
        cross join
        (
            values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)
        ) num (n)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a recursive cte:

```
with cte as (
      select iterations, incrementratio, 1 as i, incrementratio as cnt
      from t
      union all
      select iterations, incrementratio, i + 1, 
             (case when i < iterations then t.incrementratio + cnt
                   else cnt
              end)
      from t
      where i < 10
     )
select *
from cte;
```